# Python- How to return a dictionary that counts occurrences in a list of strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, updates

I'm trying to make a function that counts occurrences of the first letters of a list of strings and returns them as a dictionary.

For example:

> list=["banana","ball", "cat", "hat"]
>
> dictionary would look like: {b:2, c:1, h:1}

Here is the code I have which iterates but doesn't count properly. That's where I'm getting stuck. How do I update the values to be count?

```
def count_starts(text):
    new_list=[]
    for word in range(len(text)):
        for letter in text[word]:
            if letter[0]=='':
                new_list.append(None)
            else:
                new_list.append(letter[0])
            
    new_dict= {x:new_list.count(x) for x in new_list}


    return new_dict
```

Also, how can I avoid the out of range error given the following format:

```
def count_starts(text):
    import collections
    c=collections.Counter(x[0] for x in text)
    return c
```

Also, what do I need to do if the list contains "None" as a value? I need to count None.

Comment: `c = collections.Counter(x[0] for x in ["banana","ball", "cat", "hat"])` => `Counter({'b': 2, 'h': 1, 'c': 1})`

Comment: What is collections and how are you defining things? That's tripping me up.

Comment: that's a standard module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you seem to iterate on all letters of the word. `letter[0]` is a substring of the letter (which is a string).

You'd have to do it more simply, no need for a double loop, take each first letter of your words:

```
for word in text:
    if word:  # to filter out empty strings
        first_letter = word[0]
```

But once again [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) taking a generator comprehension to extract first letter is the best choice and one-liner (with an added condition to filter out empty strings):

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(x[0] for x in ["banana","ball", "cat", "", "hat"] if x)
```

`c` is now a dict: `Counter({'b': 2, 'h': 1, 'c': 1})`

one variant to insert `None` instead of filtering out empty values would be:

```
c = collections.Counter(x[0] if x else None for x in ["banana","ball", "cat", "", "hat"])
```

Comment: oh I see! I've never used that module before!

Comment: How can I avoid out of range error with this format?

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood Don't have any empty strings in your list.

Comment: @Rawing that's not an option as some of my test cases are empty strings.

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood I understand. The test doesn't have empty strings. But I have added a filter & added empty string to demonstrate the efficiency of the filter.

Comment: and if None is a value?

Comment: `None` is also filtered. You cannot take first letter of `None` (don't mix it up with `"None"` as string). Of course, if your list is a list of floats or something else than string, that won't work, but that's expected.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "None" is a string in the list. That is not filtered.

Comment: you mean that you want to remove `"None"` from the list? then instead of `if x` as a condition use `if x and x != "None"`.

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I want to count it. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140181/discussion-between-kelsey-greenwood-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list=["banana","ball", "cat", "hat"] 

my_dict = dict()

for word in my_list:
   try:
      my_dict[word[0]] += 1
   except KeyError:
      my_dict[word[0]] = 1
```

This increases the value of the key by 1 for the already existing key, and if they key has not been found before it creates it with the value 1

Alternative:

```
my_list=["banana","ball", "bubbles", "cat", "hat"] 
my_dict = dict()

for word in my_list:
    if word[0] in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[word[0]] += 1
    else:
        my_dict[word[0]] = 1
```

Comment: There are many better ways to do this. Counter, defaultdict, `.get`, setdefault, `if`...

Comment: Of course they are, but I decided to gave an answer that I thought it's closer to the experience Kelsey seems to have with Python. No offense, please.

Comment: @RaduIordache I haven't even learned try and except yet so I appreciate the effort!

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood - I have edited my answer with an alternative using if and else instead of try an except. Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, what do I need to do if the list contains "None" as a value? I
>   need to count None.

removing None

```
lst_no_Nones = [x for x in lis if x != None]
```

count None

```
total_None = (sum(x != None for x in lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need counter:

```
 from collections import Counter
 lst = ["banana","ball", "cat", "hat"]
 dct = Counter(lst)
```

Now, dct stores the number of times every element in lst occurs.

dct = {'b': 2, 'h': 1, 'c': 1}

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say:
`dct = Counter([word[0] for word in lst])`
and maybe
`dict(dct)`
at the end?